# How to explain the division rule in counting problem in a easy way?

Tags: combinatorics

The division rule states that "There are n/d ways to do a task if it can be done using a procedure that can be carried out in n ways, and for every way w, exactly d of the n ways correspond to way w"

I really can't understand this definition. Is there a easy way to explain this rule, not using math terms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess the best way to explain this is with an example.

Let's say we want to arrange $(1,1,2,3,4)$ in a row.

For example,

$$(1,1,2,4,3),(1,1,3,2,4)$$ Are possible arrangements.

We first assume that the two $1$'s are distinct, so we have $5!$ ways to arrange:

$$(1_a,1_b,2,3,4)$$

But for each of the $5!$ ways, we have over-counted some cases:

$$
(1,1,2,3,4)
\begin{cases}
(1_a,1_b,2,3,4)\\
(1_b,1_a,2,3,4)\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
(2,1,1,3,4)
\begin{cases}
(2,1_a,1_b,3,4)\\
(2,1_b,1_a,3,4)\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$\vdots $$

Every $2!$ of our initial $5!$ ways corresponds to one actual arrangement.

That is why to arrange $(1,1,2,3,4)$ in a row, we have:

$$\frac{5!}{2!} \space \text{ways}$$

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard this explained as:

> To count the number of cows in your field, first count the number of *legs* and then divide by four.

(Not sure who to attribute this to.)

The usual example is counting the number of subsets of size $k$ from $n$ elements.   As a first attempt, we could count them by picking $k$ elements in order.  We choose any of $n$ elements at first, then any of the $n-1$ elements left, and continue, for $$n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n- k +1)$$ choices.  But we have overcounted here, since subsets are *unordered*.  Each subset $S \subseteq \{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ of size $k$ will be counted exactly $k!$ times in the above expression.  So the number of subsets of size $k$ is $${ n \choose k} = \frac{ n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}.$$  Each "cow" ( a subset $S \subseteq \{1,2, \ldots, \}$ of size $k$) has exactly $k!$ "legs" (the orderings of $S$).

I know you said no math terms, so you can ignore this part if you want.  Let's say you want to count the size of a set $Y$, but it's a bit hard to count.  Instead you count a set $X$, and find a surjective function $f:X \rightarrow Y$.  If $f$ is $m$-to-one, so that for each $y \in Y$ there are exactly $m$ elements $x \in X$ so that $f(x) = y$.  Then we will have $$|Y| = |X|/m.$$

This can be seen bijectively:  I claim that there is a bijection $\phi: X \rightarrow Y \times \{1,2, \ldots, m\}$.  Then it will follow that $m|Y| = |X|$.  To get the bijection $\phi$ we just use $f$, but keep track of what our input was so we can go backward.  For convenience, put some ordering on $X$.  Then let $\phi(x) = (y,i)$ where $y = f(x)$ and $x$ is the $i$th element of $X$ that maps to $Y$.  Exercise: show $\phi$ is a bijection.

In the above example, we let $Y$ be the set of all subsets of size $k$ of the set $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$, and let $X$ be the set of ordered sets $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$ of elements of $X$ with no repetition.  Then define $f: X \rightarrow Y$ to map the ordered set $(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ to the unordered set $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$.  For each set $S \in Y$ there are exactly $k!$ orderings of $S$, so the map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is $k!$-to one.  e.g., $(1,2,3), (1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)$ all map to the same set $\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a class of 24 students, which you want to divide into groups of 4 for a project. The number of ways you can choose the 4 students is $24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21$ - this is $n$. The number of ways you can arrange those 4 students within the group is $4!$ - this is $d$.

So, $\frac{n}{d}$ gives the number of distinct ways to arrange the 24 students into groups of 4. In this case, each "way" is a different combination of students, and exactly $d$ ($4!$) of the ways to pick students correspond to each unique combination of students (since order doesn't matter).

I hope this helps!